# Which is more characteristic of an element absorption or emission spectrum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atoms

Absorption and emission spectrum are used to reveal the identity of an element and even to find new elements. But, which of them is more characteristic?

The mission spectrum would have more lines than the no. of lines missing in the absorption spectra simply because de-excitation can occur from any higher energy level but excitation always starts from the first energy level. So is absorption spectrum more characteristic than emission spectrum?

Answer (score 1):

Each element's emission spectrum is unique.

The absorption spectrum is the exact inverse of the emission spectrum.

As with the emission spectrum, each element has its own unique absorption spectrum.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emission_spectrum

http://theory.uwinnipeg.ca/mod_tech/node152.html

Answer (score 1):

Apart from a few special cases the absorption and emission spectra are the same. This is because for every absorption line taking from a lower state $\psi_i$ to a higher state $\psi_j$ there is a corresponding emission line when the atom decays from $\psi_j$ to $\psi_i$.

The difference tends to be more practical than theoretical. Traditionally new elements were identified in the lab by their emission lines, because it's easy to heat up a sample of your element in a flame to get them to emit light. However if you're identifying elements in the solar atmosphere you don't get to choose the experimental conditions so you use the absorption lines.